# Does this series converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I need to check by Cauchy's convergence test if this series converges:
$$a_{n}=\frac{\sin(5)}{1*2} - \frac{\sin(5^2)}{2*3}+\ldots+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\sin(5^n)}{n(n+1)}$$
I started to value
$$|a_{n+p} - a_{n}| < \epsilon$$
But don't know how to continue from:
$$\Biggl|(-1)^{n+2}*\frac{\sin(5^{n+1})}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\ldots+(-1)^{n+p+1}\frac{\sin(5^{n+p})}{(n+p)(n+p+1)}\Biggr|=\ldots$$

Comment: you can upper bound this by the reminder of a convergent series that resembles $\sum 1/n^2$

Comment: also you mean sequence in the first line, I think

Answer (score 1):

Let's the call the expression you have obtained as  $S$. Applying triangle inequality to $S$ and using the fact that $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ we get,
\begin{align*}
S \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{(n+p)(n+p+1)}
\end{align*}
By using the well known identity$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$, the above expression simplifies to
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+p}-\frac{1}{n+p+1} = \frac{p}{(n+1)(n+p+1)}.
\end{align*}
Now choose an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2} $. This implies
\begin{align*}
&&0 < \frac{1}{n+p+1}\leq\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
\implies && S\leq \frac{p}{(n+p+1)(n+1)}<\epsilon 
\end{align*}
Hence the above series is convergent